# Adding and Printing elements of an array in C

Tags: arrays, c, printing

This is a function that is trying to perform the first step of converting a CFG to Chromsky Normal From by adding 0->S as a rule to the end of the list of rules. My rules are an array of characters. For some reason it will only print the array the first time and not any time after that. I want it to print the input and then result once the array has been edited. I cannot figure out why it won't print. The output is just the original input and then blank spaces.

UPDATE: It will now print both times, but the output of the second print is the same as the first. It is not registering that I added ',','0','>','S' as elements to the array. Am I adding the elements wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//global variables
char stringCFG[200];

//a program to convert CFG to Chromsky Normal Form
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  //intialize instance variables
  FILE *CFG;
  FILE *output;
  char ch;
  int RHS= 0;
  int isThereS= 0;
  int howManyItems= 0;

  CFG= fopen(argv[1], "r");
  output= fopen(argv[2], "w");
  
  for (int i=0; i<200; i++){
      fscanf(CFG, "%c", &stringCFG[i]);
      howManyItems++;
      fprintf(output,"%c", stringCFG[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");

  for(int i=0; i<200; i++){
    if(stringCFG[i] == '>'){
      RHS= 1;
    }
    if(stringCFG[i] == ','){
      RHS= 0;
    }
    if(RHS== 1){
      if(stringCFG[i] == 'S'){
        isThereS=1;
      }
    }
  }

  if(isThereS==1){
    stringCFG[howManyItems]= ',';
    howManyItems++;
    stringCFG[howManyItems]='0';
    howManyItems++;
    stringCFG[howManyItems]='>';
    howManyItems++;
    stringCFG[howManyItems]='S';
    howManyItems++;
  }
 for(int i=0; i<200; i++){
   fprintf(output,"%c",stringCFG[i]);
  }
  fclose(CFG);
  fclose(output);
}
```

Comment: Review `while((ch = fgetc(CFG)) != EOF){  stringCFG[i]= ch;`.  It assigns `ch` to the same array element inside the `while` loop as `i` is not changed.  Is this truly intended?

Comment: I made the change from the while loop to fscanf instead, but is still not printing the new elements I added to the array

Comment: Post sample input of the CFG file. What is the size of that file?

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be here:

```
  for (int i=0; i<200; i++){
      fscanf(CFG, "%c", &stringCFG[i]);
      howManyItems++;
      fprintf(output,"%c", stringCFG[i]);
  }
```

This loop always executes 200 times regardless of what is in the file. In other words - the value of `howManyItems` will be 200 when the loop is done.

You can check that simply by printing `howManyItems` after the loop, i.e.

```
printf("After loop, howManyItems=%d\n", howManyItems);
```

Since you have:

```
char stringCFG[200];
```

then

```
stringCFG[howManyItems]= ',';  // bad.. writing to stringCFG[200]
howManyItems++;
stringCFG[howManyItems]= '0';  // bad.. writing to stringCFG[201]
howManyItems++;
...
```

will write outside of the array. That is undefined behavior.

You need to stop the first loop once the whole file has been read. Something like:

```
  for (int i=0; i<200; i++){
      if (fscanf(CFG, "%c", &stringCFG[i]) != 1)
      {
          // No more data
          break;
      }
      howManyItems++;
      fprintf(output,"%c", stringCFG[i]);
  }
```

and all the following loops must then use `howManyItems` as the upper limit.

Like

```
  for(int i=0; i<howManyItems; i++){
    if(stringCFG[i] == '>'){
      RHS= 1;
    }
    ...
  }
```

BTW: Since you want to be able to add 4 extra chars, you probably should do:

```
char stringCFG[200]; --> char stringCFG[200 + 4];
```

BTW: Hard-coding the value 200 over and over again is bad practice. Instead use a define like:

```
#define MAX_CHARS 200
```

and replace all the hard-coded `200` with `MAX_CHARS`. Then you can adjust the maximum simply by editing one line instead of multiple lines.

Comment: I added your suggestions and it is now printing the adding the characters to the array and printing! THANK YOU! For some reason it is printing the added characters on the next line, any idea why that might happen?

Comment: @maliaLikesCoding Probably you read a newline character from the file